# How to make a page redirect using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a shopping mall website using a Yahoo solution. I have multiple options for items and some items have different price dependent on the options.

Yahoo doesn't support multiple price options, and therefore I try to find a solution for this problem. One of my ideas is to make multiple pages and redirect the page dependent on options. For example, if a customer chose  model A, the page will stay in the page A which displays $1000. If a customer chose model B, the page will redirect to the page B which displays $500.

I have already made dynamic options with JavaScript, but I want to modify it to redirect a page. Here is the link of my page:

http://parseven.com/callaway_diabloedge_iron.html

In the page, there are options in the middle. If a customer chose his/her hand, it shows options, "#4 Thru AW," "Lob Wedge," and "Sand Wedge." If a customer chose either "Lob Wedge" or "Sand Wedge', the page has to redirect to a page which has a different price.

PS:

I'm using JavaScript to generate options dependent on the previous option. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <!--
    document.write('<select name="Iron(s)" onChange="javascript:     listboxchange     (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"><option value="">Select Iron(s)</option></select>')
    -->
</script>
```

Comment: Cue the onslaught of easy answers..

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? yes, the questions are the same but the answers given in the popular "original" don't even answer the question.The user wants to know how to redirect to a different page on his/her app, not navigate to some website.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use:

```
window.location = "http://my.url.here";
```

Here's some quick-n-dirty code that uses jQuery to do what you want. I highly recommend using jQuery. It'll make things a lot more easier for you, especially since you're new to JavaScript.

```
<select id = "pricingOptions" name = "pricingOptions">
    <option value = "500">Option A</option>
    <option value = "1000">Option B</option>
</select>

<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#pricingOptions").change(function() {
            if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "500") {
                window.location = "http://example.com/foo.php?option=500";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok, it seems like it's not a difficult problem. Almost everybody suggest same solution. I'm a real novice to JS. So could you specify where I have to insert that code?

Comment: I posted some sample code that uses an *onChange* event on a *select* to redirect you to the appropriate page.

Comment: Hello Vivin
Did you check my code? The options are dynamically generated by javascript. The code is:

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 <!--
 document.write('<select name="Iron(s)" onChange="javascript: listboxchange(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"><option value="">Select Iron(s)</option></select>')
 -->
 </script>
Could you tell me what to do in this case?

Comment: You'll have to perform the redirect in the *listboxchange* function. Since you're passing in the value, you can check to see if it's "500". If it is, redirect.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't really understand what you mean. If you don't mind, could you modify above code for me?

Comment: In the source for your page, check out line 54. That's where the *listboxchange* function has been defined. In that function, you need to check the value of *p_index*. If it is the value that you want, you will set *window.location* to the new URL.

Answer (score 6):

You can append the values in the query string for the next page to see and process. You can wrap them inside the link tags:

```
<a href="your_page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2">
```

You separate each of those values with the `&` sign.

Or you can create this on a button click like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href = 'your_page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2';">
```

Comment: -1 He wants to redirect using Javascript, not pass parameters into another page.

Comment: @vivin: i have also shown that a bit below, please review again. Thanks

Comment: Saw your change and tried to upvote, but says it's too old.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
document.location.href = "http://yoursite.com" + document.getElementById('somefield');
```

That would get the value of some text field or hidden field, and add it to your site URL to get a new URL (href). You can modify this to suit your needs.

Comment: MDC advises to use `window.location` over `document.location` for best cross-browser compatibility. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.location

Comment: Could you specify where I have to insert the code above? I'm a real novie to JS. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the `location` object.

```
location.href = "http://someurl";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a JavaScript function and use `window.location = 'url';`:

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jredir.htm