# How to redirect from one page to another in HTML site using HTML button

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a page redirect using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201522/how-to-make-a-page-redirect-using-javascript)

i have an HTML pages i want to use  to redirect from one page to another like response.redirect in ASP.Net. i think i must use JavaScript.

Comment: not duplicate as it specific about HTML Button - not JavaScript

Comment: found great answer here for js, html, and button: http://www.angelfire.com/nm/thehtmlsource/jazzup/redirect.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href = 'http://google.com'" />
```

or without JS

```
<form action="/contact.html">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Very nice solution for a non javascript implementation. +1

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript you can do:

```
window.location="http://someplace.com";
```

or on HTML button do this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location='http://someplace.com'" />
```

Comment: i want to navigate thru pages in the same site for example from index.html to Contact.html

Comment: Then use relative url eg: /Contact.html

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="document.location.href = 'http://google.com'"
```

OR

```
onclick="window.location = 'http://google.com'"
```

Should work fine if you add it into your  tag, replacing google with your desired address of course.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a link styled as a button. If the only thing that button does is redirects to other page, then you should use a link, it would be semantically better.